# Live version of cmd in java program's console

Tags: java

I have written this program to execute cmd commands however the output from the cmd console isn't printed 'live' to my program's console (JTextArea). It's printed at the end of the call even though I append it every line.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
private String genCmd2;
JTextArea genCmdTextArea = new JTextArea();

genCmd2 = "ping google.com";

try {
    //Execute a generated command
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(genCmd2);

    //Print output to the program's console
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        output.append(line + "\n");
        genCmdTextArea.append(output.toString());
    }

    int exitVal = process.waitFor();
    if (exitVal == 0) {
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------\nSuccess!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("exitVal != 0");
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("IOException exception during process:");
    e.printStackTrace();
    genCmdTextArea.append("\n\n" + e.toString());
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("Interrupted exception during process:");
    e.printStackTrace();
    genCmdTextArea.append("\n\n" + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: After each line try to use repaint method of text area

Comment: Added genCmdTextArea.repaint(); after append and the issue still persists.

Comment: Please also try validate method

Comment: None of these work.It might have something to do with the app freezing when I click the command is being executed.